# Change the output color of the coffeescript REPL (no yellow)

Tags: coffeescript, read-eval-print-loop

The coffee-script REPL by default prints its outputs in yellow, which is hardly readable when your background is white. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to configure it, but I don't want to change my background permanently to black just because of this issue.

Do you know know whether the coffee REPL is configurable? If not, is there an alternative? Disabling colored output completely would be fine for me, too.

I'm using Arch Linux and CoffeeScript version 1.6.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, I redefined yellow to be Blue by adding this to my `.Xdefaults` file:

```
!yellow
*color3: Blue
*color11: Blue
```